# Are there any academic papers on the "Adjective like (article) Noun" construction/ phrase?

Tags: english, theoretical-linguistics, parts-of-speech, morphosyntax, construction-grammar

I am currently working on a paper about the "Adj like (article) Noun" construction. Some would consider that which comes after the "like"-part to be a prepositional phrase if "like" is understood as a preposition, while others consider it an adjective; but this latter view is in my opinion counterintuitive. Anyway; are there any papers on this topic that I could use as sources? It would be most helpful if there were papers with a construction grammar viewpoint on this, but others would be fine as well. I see that some call this "comparative construction" but only in the context of other constructions, and mostly just as a footnote, and there are almost no papers dealing primarily with this exact construction.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you give us a couple of examples of such phrases, please?

Comment: Of course; there are many instances, many of them even idiomatized; let's say "high like a mountain", "dry like a desert", "fried like a chicken" etc.

Comment: Can't help you myself, I'm afraid, but perhaps [this chapter here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-6989-6_8) may present some useful arguments on both sides regarding the categorial status of *like*.

Comment: You might find these being referred to as equative constructions.

Comment: It would be good to edit those examples into your post! :)

Answer (score -3):

From what I see you confuse several things here.
On the one hand you cannot take *like* and just change the word class. And then argue it has a different meaning.
For example when you use like as a adjective. It needs a noun after it. Otherwise it won't be able to act as an adjective. And when I say after it I mean directly after it. A determiner in between will automatically change *like* into a preposition. In this position the word like cannot have any other role than being a adjective. A very common example for this would be "like mind" in a sentence like: We are of like mind. Or you say: We are of like height. This is the only possible way for like being used in the sense of an adjective.
Your examples all feature like as a different word class.

But in all your examples you present like as a preposition which is followed by an determiner and a noun.

Comment: Is this answer based on any academic papers? Statements like "A determiner in between will automatically change like into a preposition" should have a source to be helpful.

Comment: “like_6 Adjective - Definition, Pictures, Pronunciation and Usage Notes: Oxford Advanced American Dictionary at OxfordLearnersDictionaries.com,” like_6 adjective - Definition, pictures, pronunciation and usage notes | Oxford Advanced American Dictionary at OxfordLearnersDictionaries.com, accessed February 12, 2021, https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/like_6.

And you can check any other dictionary entries like Cambridge etc.
Or simply go and read the Longman Grammar.

Comment: Learners dictionaries are not suitable as resources for linguists or linguistics students. For a start dictionaries are utterly useless on parts of speech, which is not surprising because they are dictionaries and not grammars. Secondly your assumptions there are very simplistic. For example in *so dangerous a situation*, the word *dangerous* is an adjective and not a preposition despite having an article between it and the following noun. Furthermore there are many other tests that indicate adjective- or preposition-hood. *Like* passes some adjective ones and fails some preposition ones.

Comment: Although I do agree that it is, synchronically, a preposition!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.I was not talking about the syntactical rule for adjectives in general.I was solely referring to the use of _like_ as an adjective. _Like_ is according to corpus data (e.g. COCA and MICUSP) always used like this. If _like_ is used as an adjective it always follows the exact same pattern that is described in the learners and also advanced dictionaries. I never said in one sentence that this is a rule set for adjectives in general.